# How to increase the size of value of X/Y axes in Simulink scope?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to increase the size of the value shown in the X and Y axes so it can be seen in the report.

If you look at this figure, we barely see the value:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the screen to see what options they give you?

Comment: yes,but there is no way to manipulate the size of the numbers in the axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Simulink scopes have very limited formatting available. You have already accessed the styles that are exposed (plot background is one...)

There is two options

1) send to workspace toolbox and then use the plot command and edit the figure...

2) In the Simulink scope: File -> Print to figure

Depending on the exact manipulation you are after #2 is generally quicker if you are after a quick format update. Once the scope is in a figure you can goto: Edit -> Copy Options -> Figure Copy Template ... From here the "presentations" default (and apply to figure) and usually suitable for a quick report/presentation insertion.

The correct and repeatable method is #1 as you can then create an m-file specifically for your formatting needs

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple and straight-forward.

The procedures are as follows: -

---> file
---> print to figure

then open the m-figure...

---> edit
---> axes properties

from here, you format the axes to suit your report.